# Cómo agrego icono "X" para borrar datos de un editText

Tags: android

Quiero que en mi editText me aparezca el icono de una "X" que al presionarlo, me borre los datos que se han digitado en el editText.

Algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: prueba usar un plain text

Comment: Hola te recomendaria revisar este post, esta en ingles pero dan un monton de alternativas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355096/how-to-create-edittext-with-crossx-button-at-end-of-it